# How to make string longer then 15 chars appeared with ".." in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, char, long-integer

I'm seeking the most efficient way to make strings like that "abcdefghijklmnop"(longer then 15) to appear like that "abcdefghijklm.." - all of that inside MySQL query. I dont want to deal with it inside my app code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`select if(char_length(thefield) > 15, concat(substr(thefield, 1, 13), '..'), thefield)`

Comment: is it necessary to use the if condition?

Comment: @AJ yes, if `thefield` happens to be less than 15 chars, we wouldn't want to show "word..." when it's just "word".

Comment: @nick I did not know about that function, but I'm glad you told me about it, thank you. That could definitely save a headache down the line.

Comment: @Dan Breen ,please try: select length("中文") and select char_length("中文")

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(str) > 15 
        THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(str, 1, 13), "..") 
        ELSE str 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select if(length(string)> 15,concat(left(string, 15), '..'),string) from your_table
```

Comment: @AJ sorry, is concat function